# Can $\sigma$-algebras generated by intervals with rational endpoints have intervals with irrational endpoints?

Tags: measure-theory

Say we have a collections of subsets $\{\mathcal{A_i}\}$ of $\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is an interval with rational endpoints. Each $\mathcal{A}_i$ only contains intervals with rational endpoints, such as $(a, b)$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$. Suppose we generate their $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(A_i)$. Can any one of $\sigma(\mathcal{A}_i)$ contain intervals with irrational end points?

I am inclined to say that this is not possible, since by generating $\sigma$-algebras, we are only performing, possibly countably infinite, set-theoretic operations, and I think intervals with rational endpoints are closed under set-theoretic operations such as taking complements, and set difference. I am looking for a proof or a counterexample to my guess.

Comment: Consider that for every real number, we can find a sequence of rational number which increase or decrease to it

Comment: It's a hyphen, not a minus sign. `$\sigma$-algebra`, not `$\sigma-$algebra`.

Answer (score 2):

What is the union of the intervals $$[0,3],\,[0,3.1],\,[0,3.14],\,[0,3.141],\,[0,3.1415],\,[0,3.14159],,\,[0,3.141592],\,[0,3.1415926],\dots$$?